# 3 Way Switch Issues

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I am swapping out one of my 3-way switches with a smart switch. I am able to get each switch to turn the lights on independently, but neither switch can control the light while the other switch is on. Switch 1 powers Switch 2 and Switch 2 runs power to both lights. See pictures for existing wires. Any help would be appreciated to get each switch to operate the lights no matter which one is "turned on"

.[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you get us clear photos of the interiors of the boxes involved please?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell exactly what is going on from the pictures. Some additional pictures showing how wires are either grouped together (entering the boxes from conduit) or part of cables would help. The wires look like they *might* be in conduit (e.g., because of the green wire instead of bare ground) but might not (e.g., because there is a white wire connected to switch 2).

Note that in the explanation below I am ignoring ground connections. Depending on the type of switch and type of box, this may be handled directly by yoke-to-box contact or may be a bare or green wire connecting to each switch.

The way 3-way switches are *supposed* to be connected is as follows:

#### Switch 1

- Hot (usually black, but any color except white, gray, green or bare) from panel
- Travelers - *two* wires (if in conduit, any colors except white, gray, green or bare; if in cable, could potentially be any two of the three wires, but not the bare ground, but since there must be a neutral as well, the travelers in a standard /3 cable will be black and red)
- There may be additional wires connected to the *hot* screw to chain on to another location. That is not ideal primarily due to confusion. Better is to use a pigtail (wire nut to connect incoming hot to a short wire to the 3-way switch and additional wires as needed to other locations)
- Neutral (white or gray in conduit, white in cable) is *not* connected to the switch. It does need to get to the lights. Assuming the lights are connected to switch 2 (as stated by OP), the incoming neutral should connect (wire nut) to a white wire that goes *together with the travelers* to the second box.

So that means there should be three wires going between the boxes:

- Conduit: 2 non-white/gray/green/bare wires for travelers, white neutral
- Cable: black/red travelers, white neutral

#### Switch 2

Switch 2 "receives" the travelers and passes *switched hot* to the light.

- Travelers - *two* wires (if in conduit, any colors except white, gray, green or bare; if in cable, could potentially be any two of the three wires, but not the bare ground, but since there must be a neutral as well, the travelers in a standard /3 cable will be black and red)
- Switched Hot (usually black, but any color except white, gray, green or bare) going to the lights.
- Neutral (white or gray in conduit, white in cable) is *not* connected to the switch. It does need to get to the lights. The incoming neutral from Switch 1 box (not literally connected to Switch 1) should be connected to the neutral going to the lights.

#### Light Fixtures

The light fixtures will get just two wires from Switch 2:

- Switched Hot (usually black, but any color except white, gray, green or bare)
- Neutral (white or gray in conduit, white in cable)

#### Solving The Problem

Right now you have each switch acting as an On/Off *except* that if one is on then the other one will *not* turn the lights off. This would make sense if instead of two actual travelers, you have a *hot* wire connected in place of one of the travelers. Hard to say exactly. The solution is to work through this step-by-step. Two keys:

- There is no standard pattern for 3-way switches, except that they will use different screw colors (typically brass and silver). The two screws that have the *same* color are *travelers*. The other screw is the *common* connection and will be used as *hot* (switch 1) or *switched hot* (switch 2).
- Once you identify different wires, use colored electrical tape to label them:

  - Hot - black
  - Travelers - yellow
  - Switched Hot - red
  - Neutral - white - Note that this should *not* be necessary in most cases. If you find that your neutral is *not* white, that usually means something is wired incorrectly.

#### Switch 1

- Identify the incoming *hot* wire. This can be done using a Non-Contact Voltage Tester. This wire needs to connect to the *common* screw on switch 1.
- Identify the group of wires going to switch 2. Mark the two non-white wires as travelers and connect them to switch 1.
- Make sure neutral wires are connected together.

#### Switch 2

- Identify the group of wires coming from switch 1. Mark the two non-white wires as travelers and connect them to switch 2.
- The only remaining wire besides white neutral and green/bare grounds should be switched hot. Connect this wire to switch 2 common and mark it red.
- Connect neutrals together.

#### Smart Switch

The Smart Switch will most likely require *hot* and *neutral*. If so, it will need to replace switch 1, and you will need to add a pigtail to the neutral group of wires to add neutral to the switch.

If you want the Smart Switch to replace switch 2 then it gets more complicated. There may also be complications depending on how switch 1 and switch 2 communicate.

Comment: On switch one, there were two hot wires coming in, a single wire and a traveler that was not actually cut, just stripped so the copper could make contact. This goes to the switch to the left and a couple of outlets. I used this to determine the _incoming hot wire_. I flipped the switch, connected the _incoming hot wire_ to the common, connected the red wire to one traveler screw and the single black wire to the other traveler. On switch two, I made sure both wires were set to travelers, with the light going to the wire as the common. This fixed the problem. Much appreciated!